# Discrete Math: "Drop Zero in Bitstring" Recursive function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursive-algorithms

how do i define “dropzeros” of a bitstring as the result of dropping each 0 from the bitstring. 
ex) dropzeros of 11 is 11. The dropzeros of 1101 is 111. The dropzeros of 00 is the empty string. Let’s denote the dropzeros of the bitstring w by d(w), therefore d(10101) = 111 for example.
 a recursive definition of dropzeros of a bitstring is needed. 
Hint: first define the dropzeros of the empty string and any other necessary minimal base cases. (Use the symbol λ to denote the empty string and d(λ) to denote the dropzeros of the empty string. Include other base cases only as necessary.) Then consider a string w of length n + 1 as sb, where s is a bitstring of length n and b is a single bit, and express the dropzeros of w.

how do not understand how to approach is as just a simple recursive function. would i have to use substring?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If you know that $d(s)$ is some bitstring $u$, what is $d(s0)$ in terms of $u$? What is $d(s1)$ in terms of $u$?

Comment: what do you mean by s0?

Comment: The concatenation of the string $s$ and the symbol $0$

Comment: @user1045845: As Hagen said, the concatenation of the string $s$ with the bit $0$. For example, if $s=101101$, then $s0=1011010$, and $s1=1011011$.